# A partition of the unit square such that the quotient space is the Klein bottle

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, klein-bottle

> Write down a partition $X^*$ of the unit square $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ such that the quotient space is the Klein bottle.

I understand the definition of Quotient topology and Partitions, however, don't fully understand how to apply this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you know the traditional way to construct a Klein bottle from the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$:

Gluing Rule 1: Glue the bottom edge $[0,1] \times 0$ to the top edge $[0,1] \times 1$ without any twist, thereby gluing each point $(x,0)$ to the point straight above it $(x,1)$.

Gluing Rule 2: Glue the left edge $0 \times [0,1]$ to the right edge $1 \times [0,1]$ with a twist, thereby gluing each point $(0,y)$ to the point $(1,1-y)$.

These rules for gluing define a relation $\sim$ from the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ to itself: $(x,0) \sim (x,1)$ for each $x \in [0,1]$, and $(0,y) \sim (1,y-1)$ for each $y \in [0,1]$.

So given a point $(x,y) \in [0,1]$, to write the partition element containing $(x,y)$ you ask: What points is $(x,y)$ related to? And what points are those related to? And what points are those related to? And you keep going until you don't get any more points. The collection of points that you get by this process is the equivalence class that contains $(x,y)$. So let's work in cases.

Case 1: Given the point $(0,0)$. It is related to both $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$. These are both related to $(1,0)$. And now there are no new points. So you get one equivalence class
$$\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}
$$

Case 2: Given the point $(x,0)$ with $0<x<1$. It is related to $(x,1)$. And now there are no new points. So you get one equivalence class
$$\{(x,0),(x,1)\}
$$
for each $0<x<1$.

Case 3: Given the point $(0,y)$ with $0<y<1$. It is related to $(1,1-y)$. And now there are no new points. So you get one equivalence class
$$\{(0,y),(1,1-y)\}
$$
for each $0<y<1$.

Case 4: Given the point $(x,y)$ with $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$. It is not related to anything. So you get one equivalence class
$$\{(x,y)\}
$$
for each $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$.

Comment: Therefore the partition is the union of all of these equivalence classes?

Comment: also from "Gluing Rule 2" how did we conclude that gluing the left edge to the right edge with a twist we get the point $(1,1−y)$

Comment: Also, how do you find the points which each point is related to, i.e. in Case 1 you have that $(0,0)$ is related to $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ which are both related to $(1,0)$ ... how do we find these points?

Comment: @smith: No, the partition is not the _union_ of the equivalence classes; it's the set whose elements are the equivalence classes. (A partition of a set is a set of subsets of that set.)

Comment: @JackLee ohhh that makes more sense, thanks for clarifying, could you possibly answer my second two comments aswell if possible?

Comment: @smith: Lee Mosher's gluing rules are just mathematically precise ways of saying what we mean when we "glue" the left edge of the square to the right edge with a twist. The left edge is all points of the form $(0,y)$, and the right edge is all points of the form $(1,y')$; if we want to identify the point on the left edge $y$ units up from the bottom with the point on the right edge $y$ units down from the top, we have to identify $(0,y)$ with $(1,1-y)$. To see what $(0,0)$ gets identified with, you just follow both gluing rules repeatedly until you don't get anything new.

Comment: @smith: It might be helpful to look at the pictures in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle). (But note that the gluing pictured there is a little different--Wikipedia makes a twist when gluing the top & bottom of the square, not left & right.